# How to login to Acquia Cloud using Acquia Connector?

Tags: acquia-cloud

I've been having this error when logging in my subscription in Acquia Cloud:

`Error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (0)`

I think it is a PHP problem, not sure.

I want to migrate my local drupal site in the Acquia Cloud for my project.

How to resolve this error?